# php CURL post large string

Tags: php, curl

I need to use php to post a large string (6000 characters) to a server, the string is dynamically created in the php.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/mypost');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It works fine when the data_string is small, but once it gets to be over a few thousand chars it hangs.  No error in php console, just does not finish.  Interestingly, it works fine in Quercus PHP (which does not use libCurl but its own implementation), but it does not work in standard php (PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26). I need to have it work in standard php.

The accepting server is a JVM-Grizzly server.  I wrote another client in Java and it works fine posting the strings, so I don't think the problem is in the server.

I saw this post (https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/143602-long-string-passed-to-curl-postfields-not-getting-posted/) which seems promising, but could not get a solution to work.

Comment: When you specify `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` , `POST` is assumed by default. Remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`  does it work ?

Comment: no, it did not wok, still works in Quercus PHP though

Comment: If you can, post the real url, so we can test it. you can always replace it later.

Comment: The url is local, cant be tested, or I would.  I am starting to think the problem  IS in the server. I think my Grizzly server is doing somehing acceptable, but in a way that php does not expect.  I re-wrote the server compontent using JDK's Sun Server and PHP posted fine.  So, I am going to look more closely at the server code

Comment: check the `post_max_size` on the server config file

Answer (score 1):

Increase the default buffer size using the option `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE`

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/mypost');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 84000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```